# Wordpress subscriber role user cannot upload images from frontend

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I am having permissions issue with wordpress website for users with role=`subscriber`.

A user with role=`administrator` can upload images via wp media uploader from frontend just fine from the same form. But whenever a user uploads image from that same form then in firebug console I see `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` ajax which returns `0` with status `200`

And just after that ajax, another ajax is called `/wp-admin/async-upload.php` with a `302` which tries to redirect using ajax to `/wp-login.php?redirect_to=/wp-admin/async-upload.php&reauth=1`

I have tried adding various permission levels in my themes function.php but still the same error :

```
###ROLE FIX FOR UPLOAD FILES
if ( current_user_can('subscriber') && !current_user_can('upload_files') )
add_action('init', 'allow_subscriber_uploads');


function allow_subscriber_uploads() {

    $new_role = get_role('subscriber');
    $new_role->add_cap('upload_files');
}
```

All I see on media upload screen is this error: `An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later.`

Any help or hint would be much appreciated.

Wordpress Version of website is: 4.5.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to some plugin conflict and not due to permission issues for role=`subscriber`.

I also added `members` plugin after which the issue was fixed automatically.

I am still not clear how the issue was fixed but adding the members plugin seemed to help.